# I want a rapid application development tool (framework) for c#. Application ERP

Tags: c#, frameworks, rad

I want a rapid application development tool for c# to do applications ERP.
 We must make documents like Orders, Customers ... .

Comment: YOU WANT... Like your attitude man.

Answer (score 3):

You want and Microsoft delivered!

You need [Visual Studio Lightswitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2010/08/03/rapid-business-application-development-with-visual-studio-lightswitch.aspx)!  It is specifically designed to be a RAD tool within Visual Studio (itself a RAD Environment).  So you get twice the speed!

With Lightswitch

> you build with it – data-centric business applications.

and all

> ...without having to know the depths of Entity Framework or Silverlight or n-tier design.

but wait, there's more!

> It also provides so many features that all business applications have in common right out of the box - like an entire application shell, data validations and search. There are also many screen and control templates to choose from as well as a whole set of partners building additional controls, themes, templates, and plug-ins that we will make available right from the LightSwitch development environment via Visual Studio Gallery.

Comment: Lightswitch is off. dead since 2016. So maybe update answer.